# error_messages in rails are not being displayed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my users controller I have new and create action..

```
def new
 @user = User.new
end
def create
  @user.save!
end
```

and my `new.html.haml` is..

```
 - form_for @user do |f|
  = f.error_messages
  = label_tag "User Name"
  = f.text_field :user_name
  %br
  = submit_tag 'Add', :disable_with => "Creating…"
```

User.rb(Model)

```
validates_uniqueness_of  :config_name
```

But if I click on submit button with value already taken in text field it doesn't display error msg. But throws an exception.

```
 ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid in UsersController#create

    Validation failed: has already been taken
```

Please any one tell me why is it not displyaing error messages.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `#save!` which raises an exception when validations fail.  You should use `#save` or still use `#save!` but wrap it inside a rescue block.

```
def create
  if @user.save
    redirect_to @user, notice: 'Created!'
  else
    render :new
  end
```

Comment: If i m using #Save, it simply inserts the record in table not displaying error. (I want to display rails's inbuilt errors).

Comment: the only difference with `save!` and `save` is the way they react when it fails validation. `save!` raises an exception and `save` returns false. you need to add more code to your controller like in my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

see [save!](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations.html#method-i-save-21)

```
def create
  unless @user.save
     render :action => :new
  end
end
```